# Why wont elinks save anything?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, command-line, elinks

I have an Ubuntu pure terminal system (no GUI, just boots into terminal). But each time I close Elinks and go back, it does not save the history, bookmarks, or any personal settings! Please tell me why it does this and how to fix it. (This is also true with Links2 which i run with `sudo`.)

P.S. I am kinda a terminal noob. So if you have a solution please give me all the commands to use.

Comment: Why are you running your programs with `sudo`?

Comment: Otherwise links2 does not run